# How to return custom response when validation has fails using laravel form requests

Tags: laravel, validation

When we use [Laravel Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation) in our controllers and the validation fails then the Form Request will redirect back with the `errors` variable.

How can I disable the `redirection` and return a custom error response when the data is invalid?

I'll use form request to `GET|POST|PUT` requests type.

I tried the `Validator` class to fix my problem but I must use Form Requests.

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'type' => "required|in:" . implode(',', $postTypes)
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()]);
}
```

Comment: basically, you want custom error message Right?

Comment: Yes, but using `FormRequest`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: I need only disable redirection and return `FormRequest` errors

Answer (score 19):

Creating custom `FormRequest` class is the way to go.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

class FormRequest extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest
{
    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        if ($this->expectsJson()) {
            $errors = (new ValidationException($validator))->errors();
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                response()->json(['data' => $errors], 422)
            );
        }

        parent::failedValidation($validator);
    }
}
```

Class is located in `app/Http/Requests` directory. Tested & works in Laravel 6.x.

Comment: I've finally found your answer, exactly what I need.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Is there a way to do this globally for all form requests? Or in a midlleware?

Comment: @Nebster You can just extend this class in your other form request classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same but written differently:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    $errors = (new ValidationException($validator))->errors();

    throw new HttpResponseException(
        response()->json([
            'message' => "",
            'errors' => $errors
        ], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base class `FormRequest` has method [`failedValidation`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_failedValidation). Try to override it in your `FormRequest` descendant

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

class SomeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...

    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Error message: `Declaration of App\Http\Requests\PostCreate::failedValidation(App\Http\Requests\Validator $validator) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest::failedValidation(Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator)`

Comment: it seems you didn't add `use` of `Validator`

Comment: I've `use Validator` and also tired `\Validator` but not work

Comment: you should use concrete `use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;`

Comment: Ok. It's work but redirecting not disabled and I can't get errors message array from my custom request inside `failedValidation` function

Comment: I tired override function by adding this code `return $validator->errors();`

Comment: what you want to do exactly instead of redirect?

Comment: Because I use form request inside my API routes @Roman Bobrik

Comment: no, I mean, what you want to do exactly? explain all chain. maybe it possible to solve much easier

Comment: I want validate data using `Form Requests` inside API routes and return `errors` instead of redirect. @Roman Bobrik

Comment: ok, then explain detailed, how you interact with your API (ajax or not), and what you get and what you want to get. edit your post, describe all chain, hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

*use this on function*
dont forget to take on top  // use App\Http\Requests\SomeRequest;

```
$validatedData = $request->validated();
\App\Validator::create($validatedData);
```

*create request php artisan make:request SomeRequest*
ex.
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;

```
class SomeRequest extends FormRequest
{
   public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'health_id'      => 'required',
            'health'         => 'required',
        ];
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your custom request:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        response()->json([
            'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        ], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
    );
}
```