# how to get errors from laravel in response in flutter

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, dart, frontend

i am trying to get the validations errros on signup but the flutter is just showing error code with the string but as we know laravel send whole array of errors which i am unable to get

here is my code

```
on<SignUpUser>( (event, emit) async {
          final dio = getIt<Dio>();
          dynamic result = await dio.post('/api/register', data: {
            'name': event.name,
            'email': event.email,
            'password': event.password,
            'password_confirmation': event.passwordConfirmation
          },
            options: Options(
              // followRedirects: false,
              // maxRedirects: 0,
              // validateStatus: (status) => status! < 500,
              headers: {
                "Accept" : "application/json",
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
              },
            ),

          );
          // print(result.body);
          if(result.statusCode == 422){
            print(result.body['errors']); //print out validation errors
          }
    });
```

i have tried most of the stuff but not getting any understanding on this

Comment: Can you provide more information as what is the exact error flutter is showing, maybe the result.body json formatted

Comment: all i am getting is 
DioException [bad response]: The request returned an invalid status code of 422.
no matter what i print i just get this

Comment: if i just pass the data which is acceptable in laravel validation i do get the response in print but when validation fails and i want the error. there dont show up. i only get the message which i just posted in the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

`but as we know laravel send whole array of errors[...]` - I don't think that's true. Sending a `422` with no body should be the default behavior and is also the most secure thing to do. You can, however, return the the errors explicitly by adding a `FormRequest` with a function like this one:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
    if ($this->expectsJson()) {
        $errors = (new ValidationException($validator))->errors();
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            response()->json(['data' => $errors], 422)
        );
    }
    parent::failedValidation($validator);
}
```

See similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56438563/how-to-return-custom-response-when-validation-has-fails-using-laravel-form-reque).

Comment: no we wont be need to do that we can just use DioException in flutter to get thos validation messages
 try {
        dynamic result = await dio.request(
          '/api/$url',
          data: data,
          options: Options(
            method: method,
            headers: headers,
          ),
        );
        return result;
      } on DioException catch  (e) {
        return e.response;
      }

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Make sure to accept your own answer so it appears on top of this one, I'm going to leave that one up, just in case someone doesn't get the errors or needs to extend them, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use DioExceptions like this

```
static dynamic globalRequest(url, data, method, [headers]) async {
if (headers == null) {
  Map<String, dynamic> headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  final dio = getIt<Dio>();
  try {
    dynamic result = await dio.request(
      '/api/$url',
      data: data,
      options: Options(
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
      ),
    );
    return result;
  } on DioException catch  (e) {
    return e.response;
  }
}
```

}

```
on<SignUpUser>((event, emit) async {
    Map<String, dynamic>data= {
      'name': event.name,
      'email': event.email,
      'password': event.password,
      'password_confirmation': event.passwordConfirmation
    };
    final result= await GlobalRequest.globalRequest('register',data,'post');
    print(result);
});
```